# Internet Explorer tab for Opera

Tags: internet-explorer, opera

Is there any way to run Internet Explorer in a tab in Opera?  Much of the corporate website where I work is built for Internet Explorer 6 (what is up with *that*?), so if I want to access it using my default browser, it has to either be Internet Explorer 6 or Firefox with the extension *[IE Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE_Tab)*.  Is there any way to do the same with Opera?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Neptune](http://cybernetnews.com/2008/04/28/ie-tab-in-opera/) to add *IE Tab*-like functionality to Opera.

Answer (score 3):

Opera also has an "Open with" menu item.  If a page doesn't work properly, right click anywhere on the page (except on an image) and select "Open with" -> "Internet Explorer".  The list will also include other installed browsers such as Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: This does it very good.

Comment: No longer works in Opera v36.0

Answer (score 1):

Try using an Opera add-on called [*Install Chrome Extensions*](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/?display=en) and then install the Chrome extension [*IE Tab*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/IE%20tabs).